# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to share a Rational Test Workbench report?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

The Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight is able to generate a report with the `.moebreport` extension.

From [this IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.mobtest.doc/topics/t_view_rep.html):

> You can choose to view the test reports on the mobile device, on an
>   emulator, or on the test workbench.

Is it possible to change the report's extension (e.g. to `.html`) so that other people who do  not have Rational Test Workbench installed still be able to view it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the extension, but you can easily see the report in a browser using the following REST service:

```
http://hostname:port/moeb/service/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.services.reports.IReportService/?action=browse&path=path_of_the_moebreport
```

For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7878/moeb/service/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.core.moeb.services.reports.IReportService/?action=browse&path=%2FMobile%2Ftest4_1369647998749.xmoebreport
```

RTW should be open to be able to vizualize a report in a browser

Comment: But if one does not have RTW installed, RTW cannot be opened to view the report?

Comment: I think dom means that as long as RTW is running on a host machine, users can load a URL to view it on that server via browser.